# Python Pandas df.isin shows inaccurate results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a point cloud of 6 millions x, y and z points I need to process. I need to look for specific points within this 6 millions xyz points and I have using pandas `df.isin()` function to do it. I first save the 6 millions points into a pandas dataframe (save under the name `point_cloud`) and for the specific point I need to look for into a dateframe as well (save under the name `specific_point`). I only have two specific point I need to look out for. So the output of the `df.isin()` function should show 2 `True` value but it is showing 3 instead.

In order to prove that 3 True values are wrong. I actually iterate through the 6 millions point clouds looking for the two specific points using `iterrows()`. The result was indeed 2 True value. So why is `df.isin()` showing 3 instead of the correct result of 2?

I have tried this, which result `true_count` to be 3

```
label = (point_cloud['x'].isin(specific_point['x']) & point_cloud['y'].isin(specific_point['y']) & point_cloud['z'].isin(specific_point['z'])).astype(int).to_frame()
true_count = 0

for index, t_f in label.iterrows():
     if int(t_f.values) == int(1):
          true_count += 1

print(true_count)
```

I have tried this as well, also resulting in `true_count` to be 3.

```
for t_f in (point_cloud['x'].isin(specific_point['x']) & point_cloud['y'].isin(specific_point['y']) & point_cloud['z'].isin(specific_point['z'])).values
true_count = 0

     if t_f == True:
          true_count += 1
```

Lastly I tried the most inefficient way of iterating through the 6 millions points using `iterrows()` but this result the correct value for `true_count` which is 2.

```
true_count = 0

for index_sp, sp in specific_point.iterrows():
     for index_pc, pc in point_cloud.iterrows():

          if sp['x'] == pc['x'] and sp['y'] == pc['y'] and sp['z] == pc['z]:
               true_count += 1

print(true_count)
```

Do anyone know why is `df.isin()` behaving this way? Or have I seem to overlook something?

Comment: [Provide a copy of the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

`isin` function for multiple `columns` with and will fail to look the dataframe per row, it is more like check the product the list in dataframe .

So what you can do is

```
checked=point_cloud.merge(specific_point,on=['x','y','z'],how='inner')
```

For example, if you have two list `l1=[1,2];l2=[3,4]`, using `isin` , it will return any row match `[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]`

Comment: Hello WeNYoBen, the `df.merge` function will sift out the specific points from the 6 millions points. But what I need to do is to look for these specific points and make changes to it. e.g. changing the RGB values of these points. I am trying to look for the points among the 6 millions points and `if True` make changes to these points. Thanks.